# Django-rest-Framework + internationalization

Tags: django-rest-framework

I can't make internationalization of the django-rest-framework work with Content-Type = application / json.
I try to make POST requests, and only when Content-Type = application / x-www-form-urlencoded is set, error messages are returned according to the HEADER Accept-Language.

Comment: What happen when you run it with the `application / json` content type?

Comment: Error messages return without internationalization